# Create zip files using spark(python)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a zip file from several files. For example, I have 3 files

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I want to create a zip folder that contains all these files

Is there some way to create zip folder containing multiple files in Spark(Python)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all spark is a framework which is also in python language. I did not understand how do you relate zip files and spark in this question.

If you want to create zip files in python, check out `zipfiles` library. Try and if you're stuck copy your code here. Then we will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 from zipfile import ZipFile  
 # create a ZipFile object
    with ZipFile('sampleDir.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
        # Iterate over all the files in directory
        for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(dirName):
            for filename in filenames:
                #create complete filepath of file in directory
                filePath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
                # Add file to zip
                zipObj.write(filePath)

o/p:

sampleDir/file1.csv                      2018-11-30 21:44:46         2829
sampleDir/file2.csv                      2018-11-30 21:44:36         3386
sampleDir/file3.csv                      2018-11-30 21:44:56         3552
```